# mysqli_insert_id Not Working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get last autoincrement id from INSERT/UPDATE query, i am trying this way, but its not working, it just echo `id=0` every time.

PHP

```
require_once('conn.php'); 
$temp = 'temp';

$query = "INSERT INTO temp (temp) VALUES('$temp')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR);

$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
echo 'id = '.$id;
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Comment: Does the temp table contain an auto increment column?

Comment: Shit, my bad that was the error, its working now.

Comment: Did you fire the query in mysql server? Is it working?

Comment: BTW, +1 for using proper error handling

Comment: Please note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Salman A this is not working with UPDATE query `$query = "UPDATE temp SET temp='$temp' WHERE id='2'";` it echo `id=0`.

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois how to fix it.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet or in short: use PDO with prepared statements - this way you even improve performance, if you're inserting more than one row.

Comment: @TallboY: the function is called `mysql` **insert** `id` for an obvious reason. Besides, you have a `2` in your query which is the id you want. Not sure why you cannot use that.

Comment: @Salman A `2` is just for testing purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the query to.

```
INSERT INTO `temp` (`temp`) VALUES('$temp')
```